# buffer overflow c(gets function)

Tags: c, security, buffer-overflow, gets

There is the following code, I need to return an access level that's under 0x30 and not equal to 0 or 2:

```
int login() {
int accessLevel = 0xff;
char username[16];
char password[32];
printf("Username (max 15 characters): ");
gets(username);
printf("Password (max 31 characters): ");
gets(password);

if (!strcmp(username, "admin") && !strcmp(password, "{{ create_long_password() }}")) {
    accessLevel = 2;
} else if (!strcmp(username, "root") && !strcmp(password, "{{ create_long_password() }}")) {
    accessLevel = 0;
} else if (!strcmp(username, "artist") && !strcmp(password, "my-password-is-secret")) {
    accessLevel = 0x80;
}

return accessLevel;
}
```

I entered into the user name 16 'a' which reset the accessLevel to 0(and then added space which set access to 20 and gives me the desired output).
But, I would expect the buffer to overwrite password, not accessLevel since it's the "following memory".
I imagine I'm misunderstanding how the buffer works and would like an explanation.
Also, why did the 16th char reset to 0?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no way to avoid a potential buffer overflow using `gets()`. It's the only function so bad it was actually removed from the C standard. **DO NOT USE IT**. `fgets()` is the safe alternative.

Comment: Also, since writing past the end of an array is undefined behavior, there's no point in attempting to reason about whatever happens as a consequence when you intentionally do so.

Comment: Not my question, this was a challenge in a ctf.

Comment: If you do want to reason about it, you have to inspect the assembly code produced by a particular compilation (compiler options etc, and including the machine code in the library), because there is no concept of undefined behavior at assembly level (at least not in the same sense as in C).

Comment: Security note: Although this is learner's code and there is much to consider, a function that queries user-name and password should clean up data before returning. I'd expect something like `memset(username, 0, sizeof username);` and the same for `password` just before the `return`.  Further, code should call a secure input function too.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ordering of local variables on the stack (assuming there *is* a stack) is not guaranteed to be in any particular order.  It depends largely on the types of the variables and the required alignment of each of them, and can change depending on the compiler or on optimization settings.

In this case, it sounds like the variables were pushed onto the stack in the order they appear in code, which would mean that their addresses would progressively decrease.

Comment: So the addresses in a stack are "negative"?
I mean if the first is position is 0 and it's going down, the stack is going negative...

Comment: @AviShabat That (which direction stack grows) is CPU (and sometimes operating system) dependent.

Answer (score 2):

Strcmp will match an arbitrary amount of chars, given by the first instance of null termination char. All string literals must be null terminated with \0

Using strncmp will only compare and amount of chars given in the arguements